# Scala Numeric init with constant 0

Tags: scala, numeric

Lets I have a utility class called MathUtil.

and it looks like this .

```
abstract class MathUtil(T:Numeric){
   def nextNumber(value:T)
   def result():T
}
```

Lets I subclass it this way

```
class SumUtil[T:Numeric] extends MathUtil[T]{
   private var sum:T = 0
   override def nextNumber(value:T){
     sum = sum + value
   }
   override def result():T = sum
}
```

I have  a problem with the statement

```
private var sum:T = 0
```

Now , I have to initialize to sum to 0. I would guess any numeric to have a way to represent 0. Im pretty new to scala. How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I have a followup question. Lets say I have a class which has overrideable member of type MathUtils.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Numeric` type class instance](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) has a `zero` method that does what you want:

```
class SumUtil[T: Numeric] extends MathUtil[T] {
   private var sum: T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero
   override def nextNumber(value: T) {
     sum = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(sum, value)
   }
   override def result(): T = sum
}
```

Note that you also need the instance for the `plus` method, unless you import `Numeric.Implicits._`, in which case you can use `+`. You can also clean the code up a bit by not using the context bound syntax in this case:

```
class SumUtil[T](implicit ev: Numeric[T]) extends MathUtil[T] {
   import Numeric.Implicits._
   private var sum: T = ev.zero
   override def nextNumber(value: T) {
     sum = sum + value
   }
   override def result(): T = sum
}
```

This is exactly equivalent: the context bound version is just syntactic sugar for this implicit argument, but if you need to use that argument explicitly (as you do here, for its `zero`), I find it cleaner to write the desugared version.

Comment: Hey Travis!  Good to see you posting here (this is Ben from Austin).  Unfortunately this Numeric stuff is, IMO, just utterly fugly.  It turns out it's also slow as hell.  IMO the whole Scala implicit mechanism is clunky, brittle and hard-to-understand and you still need other junk like @specialized, which is also majorly hacked up.  I think this stuff would be much better expressed using C++-style class specialization, which would *just* *work* the way everyone expects, essentially by copying the implementation with s/int/double/ or whatever.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond: Hi, Ben! I agree that `Numeric` is a mess, and I can't remember the last time I used it in my own code, but I don't personally think the problem is the way Scala implements type classes (which I've actually grown to like).

Answer (score 0):

I think that there needs to be a little clarification of exactly what you're trying to accomplish. From the Scala docs, the Numeric type itself is generic. My feeling here is what you actually want is to describe a MathUtil abstraction that handles any Numeric[T] rather than subclasses of Numeric[_] which is what your code is currently describing. Here is the correct implementation based on that assumption.

```
//Define a MathUtil that works on any T
abstract class MathUtil[T] {
    def nextNumber(value: T)
    def result(): T
}

//Define a SumUtil that works on any T that has an available Numeric
//Will search implicit scope, but also allows you to provide an
//implementation if desired.
class SumUtil[T](implicit n: Numeric[T]) extends MathUtil[T] {
    //Use the Numeric to generate the zero correctly.
    private var sum: T = n.zero
    //Use the Numeric to correctly add the sum and value
    override def nextNumber(value: T) = sum = n.plus(sum, value)
    override def result(): T = sum
}

//Test that it works.
val a = new SumUtil[Int]
val b = List(1,2,3)

b map a.nextNumber //Quick and dirty test... returns a meaningless list
println(a.result)  //Does indeed print 6
```

If the above doesn't do what you want, please clarify your question.

Comment: You're not right... `[T : Numeric]` is a context bound and will expand to `[T](implicit n: Numeric[T])`, so your code is almost the same as the OP's except for the `n.zero`.